# Can I use spring data repository interface for cassandra async inserts?

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

```
@Repository
public interface RoundRepository extends CassandraRepository<Round, String> {
    List<Round> findByInstanceId(String instanceId, Pageable pageable);

    Round findByInstanceIdAndRound(String instanceId, long round);

    long countByInstanceId(String instanceId);
}
```

I have repositories like this.
And I want to use them to do async inserts and sync everything else. Can I do it in this style without native queries via AsyncCassandraTemplate?
Didn't found any tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Spring has a doc on getting [Async Query Results](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-async) via custom repository methods.  Basically, you can use the `@Async` annotation and then wrap the return type with one of the *Future types.

So in your case, `countByInstanceId` might look something like this:

```
@Async
ListenableFuture<long> countByInstanceId(String instanceId);
```